# Known voltage/current source

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, current-measurement, voltage-reference

I am working on an EVM for an electricity meter. Its manual says the EVM requires a known voltage and current source for the calibration.

I bought a [power supply](http://se.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=15001&langId=46&urlRequestType=Base&partNumber=1437528&storeId=10177) and measure the output of the PSU by a multimeter. But, it read the output with 1V difference. I assume the PSU might have a better accuracy but still doubt if the PSU has some inaccuracy (may be uncalibrated).

Is there any mark or standard for a PSU to show its accuracy? What type of device (PSU) do you use to calibrate a PSU or to have a known voltage/current reference?

Comment: How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: Off by 1 volt in 300? That's 0.3% and fairly reasonable. Off by 1 volt in 30 is not reasonable. The voltmeter and ammeter accuracy should be specified in the manual. I would expect the voltmeter to be more accurate than the ammeter.

Comment: the user manual says it can have sub 0.1% accuracy with the calibration. My goal to have at least 0.2% accuracy. I check the datasheet of the multimeter, it says the best accuracy for AC is 0.4% + 30. I don't know what is 30 mean. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1504908.pdf

Comment: As a sample, I set the PSU to 231 VAC, the multimeter reads 230.22 VAC, the electricity meter reads 228.94 VAC(not calibrated). I can't be sure which one is more precise

Answer (score 1):

I would use a precision voltage reference such as the [LT1019](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1019fd.pdf)

Comment: It's not that great - it's OK but there are better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a calibration facility of your own, then in order to be sure of what you're doing you could buy a good digital multimeter and have it calibrated by a facility with resources traceable to some organization where you live which is like the National Institute of Science and Technology (NIST) here in the US.